# How much clearance is needed between window and wall for portable AC hose?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning, clearance

We have a project upcoming to replace the windows in our condo. We have the option to add portable AC hose vents to the spandrel, and I need to decide on the placement of the spandrel in the windows.

The room has a full east wall of windows. There is a built in closet on the south wall of the room which extends into the room. The east closet wall is very close to the southern most window. I'm currently out of the unit and don't have the measurements of exactly how far the clearance from the window to the closet is, but I can get that before making a concrete decision.

If we were to add the spandrel and AC hose vents beneath a casement window at the southernmost point of the wall (i.e. directly parallel with the very close closet wall), how much clearance would be required that we would be able to successfully attach an AC hose to the vent? The hose would need to turn 90 degrees immediately from the vent, then attach to the AC unit in front of the closet.

Presumably, this depends on the exact model of AC unit, as they'll have different hose materials and sizes, but is there a rough rule of thumb as to the minimum perpendicular clearance from the window to another object for this?

The floor plan of the room is like so:

[image]

Comment: A 4" hose will take roughly twice as much room as a 2" hose and about 1/2 as much as an 8" hose, so I think it's going to be really hard for someone to estimate without knowing what size hose you're going to use. Since _you_ don't know that yet, it's going to be even harder to make a guess. As a rough estimate, though, I'd go with "diameter of hose plus minimum bend radius of said hose".

Comment: Keep in mind that **single-hose** portable air conditioners are a design fiasco. They eject large quantities of air from the room, *yet provide no provision whatsoever for makeup air*.  Thus air is drawn in through the natural leaks in the house, which builders do their best to *eliminate*. As such, always and only use 2-hose portables, and have provisions built for 2 hoses per A/C.  Also, hoses should be kept as short as possible so the hose openings should be nearest where the A/C will be.